# Создать новое событие программно

Tags: c#

Надо создать новое событие, для созданного программно объекта. Событие Click. Как это сделать? С чего начать?

Comment: что за объект? вы написали класс и для него хотите написать событие? или что?

Comment: Я программно создал Button и надо написать для него событие.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

первый вариант(традиционный):

```
YourButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(YourButtonClick);//подписываемся на событие

//обрабатываем событие
private void YourButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("He's Alive");
}
```

второй вариант(лямбда-синтаксис):

```
YourButton.Click += (s,e)=>MessageBox.Show("He's Alive");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Первое мне больше нравится.

Comment: Джеффри Рихтер утверждает, что если метод занимает больше 4 логических строк кода, он должен быть именованым, но для "маленьких" обработчиков и анонимные методы годны

Comment: А мне дак второй вариант больше нравится - он более универсальный. Первый вариант годится для разработки Desktop приложений, я же пишу Windows RT приложения (под Windows 8) и там несколько иначе все работает.

Comment: Вы уверены, что под WinRT-таргетом можно использовать лямбды, но не методы?

(Подсказка: этого не может быть, поскольку лямбда компилируется в метод (возможно, вспомогательного класса).)

Comment: Ну вот мой вариант рабочего кода:

`Button enterData = new Button();            enterData.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
enterData.Click += async (s, e1) =>
{
   if (service.Text != "" && login.Text != "" && password.Text != "")
   {
       OutputData.Text += service.Text + " " + site.Text + " " + login.Text + " " + password.Text + "\n";
       popup.IsOpen = false;
   }
   else
   {
       MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Повторите ввод данных, заполнив все поля отмеченные звездочной.", "Ошибка!");
       await dlg.ShowAsync();
   }
};`